# Change html in children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html document which goes to create excel report.
Here is a link to sample html in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UrM7k/

I wish to edit the html content so that instead
of two lines for each time period I will have one line,
 seperated by " - ".
Here is some code I've tried:

```
var fromTime = $(div).find("td.date_range");
    //replace new line between dates with "-" sepeartor
    var replaced = fromTime.html().replace(/<br\s?\/?>/, " - ");
    //fromTime.html(replaced);
```

it does remove the extra line,
but it changes all of the periods to be the same like the first.

Would appreicate any help.
Thanks,
Omer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. You could use `each()` to iterate and `this` to reference the current item:

http://jsfiddle.net/4v3sE/

```
$("td.date_range").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace(/<br\s?\/?>/, " - "));
});
```

But I think this solution is cleaner:

http://jsfiddle.net/wfYnH/

```
$("td.date_range br").replaceWith(' - ');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(div).find("td.date_range").each(function() {
    var replaced = $(this).html().replace(/<br\s?\/?>/, " - ");
    $(this).html(replaced);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

fromTime is the entire set of cells, but you are only calling replace() once on it.  I suspect you will need to iterate over that collection, and do the replace() call for each one separately.